# Notation for "such that" on a set-builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, notation

This may be a really simple question to answer, but I need to know, with references to prove my affirmation, that the actual notation for "such that" on a set builder notation is the colon or vertical line, but not the oblique line. Can anybody help me with some reference for this notation?
Thank you very very much.

Comment: You want references for that? Set builder notation is $\textbf{notation}$: i.e., if you want to use a different symbol, go for it.

Comment: There are many cases where people use nonstandard notation.  As long as it is established before hand that the people are using the same notation it is okay.  Rather then "actual notation" it might be better to say "standard notation" or "most commonly used notation"

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was serching for references that establishes the vertical line or colon as standard notation, and that gives some reason for not using "/" instead of the other ones. This notation is going to be use on a very elementary material for school students.

Comment: You could make up reasons why $/$ is a bad choice, but you could just as well make up such reasons for $:$ and $|$.  The real reason is just that it's the notation that everyone else uses.  In any case, it seems rather bizarre that you need a reference to "prove" this, especially if this is just for students.

Comment: It never occurred to me that the ":" in the weirdly-named "set-builder" notation was the mathematical notation for "such that". I suppose, then, that "{" is the notation for "the set of all", but what does "}" stand for?

Comment: Seems to me I've also seen a semicolon ";" used for "such that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\vert$ and $:$ are used.
$\vert$ perhaps, being the most historical.
For clarity of notation, $:$ is preferred.
For example imagine using $\vert$ in the definition of $\{ x : |x| < 5 \}$.

Though I don't know the source of the recent amateurish use of /, it is to be avoided since it is  not accepted, causes confusion and lacks notational clarity.  For example, $\{ x/y \ / \ 1/xy < 10 \}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know it is to be avoided for that reasons, but I was looking for some reference, if there was some. I found this link from Springer: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-0-85729-829-4%2F1.pdf , do you think it can work as one?